# Change Wix Product version number using NANT XmlPoke

Tags: build, wix, nant, wix3.9

I ran into this issue recently - when I try to replace the Wix Product version number using [NANT XMLPOKE](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) task, it returns the following error message "No matching nodes found".

```
<xmlpoke file="..\Setup\abc.wxs" xpath="//Wix/Product[@Version]" value="${version.label}" >
```

Initially I thought that this was an issue with XPATH statement that I wrote. So I kept trying with different XPATH (like \Wix) and I kept getting the same message back.

Understood from a blog that this is happening due to the namespace definition with the WiX element. Please find below the solution, in case someone doesn't find the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens because of the namespace definition within the Wix element. You have to add the below changes to get the XMLPOKE working:

```
<xmlpoke file="..\Setup\abc.wxs" xpath="//wx:Wix/wx:Product/@Version" value="${version.label}" >
      <namespaces>
        <namespace prefix="wx" uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
      </namespaces>
    </xmlpoke>
```

Reference: [Soledad Pano's blog](http://solepano.blogspot.com/2006/11/problem-with-nants-xmlpoke-task.html)